# Trying to install Quartz.net, having issue running server

Tags: installation, quartz.net

So I have been following the instructions [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx) for installing Quartz.NET. However, when I try running "Quartz.Server.exe -i" from the command prmopt, I get this error:

```
Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : The service terminated abnormally, Topshelf.Host
ConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
[Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: SWITCH: i (True
)
[Success] Name QuartzServer
[Success] DisplayName Quartz Server
[Success] Description Quartz Job Scheduling Server
[Success] ServiceName QuartzServer
   at Topshelf.Configurators.ValidateConfigurationResult.CompileResults(IEnumera
ble`1 results)
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.New(Action`1 configureCallback)
   at Topshelf.HostFactory.Run(Action`1 configureCallback)
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: small world - i am using the same tutorial (2 hours later) and ran into the same problem as you.  i will post if i find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the command line without the "-i"

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quartz.Net>Quartz.Server.exe
```

Comment: If you look at the tutorial and look closely at the screenshot of the Service (right under where it says 'If you wanted to name the Quartz service something else then that’s also possible'), you'll see the service is STOPPED.  So, try manually stopping the service first.  Then run the Quartz.Server.exe with no -i and you should see an output like the one in the tutorial.

Comment: Hey! That seemed to have done the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to install it as a service just use:

```
Quartz.Server.exe install
```

instead of -i or -install or /install or ....

if you will run it without any parameter it will be run as command line application

Answer (score 0):

I got into same error, and got 'Access Denied' when running through services.msc. Finally the issue was due to a misconfigured entry in quartz config ( wrong delegate ).