# Install Quartz.NET as a windows service on Windows 10 - ERROR

Tags: quartz.net

I'm trying to install Quartz.NET as a windows service on Windows 10.
The version of Quartz.NET is v2.6.2 and i have used [this tutorial](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx) to do it. In other OS's like Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 i have installed this version successfully.

When i run the command to instal as a service:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Quartz.NET>Quartz.Server.exe install`

I have the following successful message:

> Configuration Result:
>   [Success] Name QuartzServer
>   [Success] DisplayName Quartz Server
>   [Success] Description Quartz Job Scheduling Server
>   [Success] ServiceName QuartzServer
>   Topshelf v3.1.135.0, .NET Framework v4.0.30319.42000
>
> Running a transacted installation.
>
> Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
>   Installing Quartz Server service
>   Installing service QuartzServer...
>   Service QuartzServer has been successfully installed.
>   Creating EventLog source QuartzServer in log Application...
>
> The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.
>
> The Commit phase completed successfully.
>
> The transacted install has completed.

But when i run the following command (Quartz.Server.exe -i) to see whether my installation has been successful installed, i have the following message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Quartz.NET>Quartz.Server.exe -i
>
> Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : An exception occurred creating the host, Topshelf.HostConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
>   [Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: SWITCH: i (True)
>   [Success] Name QuartzServer
>   [Success] DisplayName Quartz Server
>   [Success] Description Quartz Job Scheduling Server
>   [Success] ServiceName QuartzServer
>      at Topshelf.Configurators.ValidateConfigurationResult.CompileResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
>      at Topshelf.HostFactory.New(Action`1 configureCallback)
>   Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : The service terminated abnormally, Topshelf.HostConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
>   [Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: SWITCH: i (True)
>   [Success] Name QuartzServer
>   [Success] DisplayName Quartz Server
>   [Success] Description Quartz Job Scheduling Server
>   [Success] ServiceName QuartzServer
>      at Topshelf.Configurators.ValidateConfigurationResult.CompileResults(IEnumerable`1 results)
>      at Topshelf.HostFactory.New(Action`1 configureCallback)
>      at Topshelf.HostFactory.Run(Action`1 configureCallback)

All of the commands have been run in Administration mode.
Is there any configuration that i have missed on Windows 10?

**EDIT**

I don't have access to start and stop buttons in Quartz Server windows service, they are disabled.

If i run Quartz.Server.exe on command prompt its executes the scheduler perfectly. But when i run Quartz.Server.exe -i it gives me the error that i have mention on my first post. And i still don't have access to start and stop buttons

**EDIT 2**

I have installed the last version of Quartz and the problem is the same comparing to previous version, except the unknown command-line option was found (see error message).

Quartz v2.6.2

Topshelf v3.1.4.357038

> Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : An exception occurred creating the host, Topshelf.HostConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
>   [Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: SWITCH: i (True)

Quartz V3.0.7

Topshelf v4.1.0.172

> Topshelf.HostFactory Error: 0 : An exception occurred creating the host, Topshelf.HostConfigurationException: The service was not properly configured:
>   [Failure] Command Line An unknown command-line option was found: DEFINE: i =

Maybe this could be some configuration that is affecting Topshelf.

**EDIT 3**

I have been confirmed that this error is also being fired in Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard production server, when running the command Quartz.Server.exe -i. The difference is that in production environment we have start/stop buttons enabled, but in windows 10 machine i don't have start/stop buttons enabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to install Quartz.net, having issue running server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951842/trying-to-install-quartz-net-having-issue-running-server)

Comment: That didn't resolve my problem, i have edit my first post with some answers to that.